# When does Java type inference produce an infinite type?

Tags: java, programming-languages, wildcard, type-inference

The JLS mentions in the type inference algorithm (§15.12.2):

> It is possible that the process above yields an infinite type. This is permissible,
>   and Java compilers must recognize such situations and represent them appropriately using cyclic data structures.

However, I'm unable to find an actual example where javac produces an infinite type.
I think it ought to produce one in the following case:

```
<T> T pick(T a, T b) { ... }

pick("string", 3);
```

Both String and Integer are Comparable<themselve>, so their common supertype should be `Comparable<? extends Comparable<? extends Comparable<? ...>>>` (infinite).

I can do:

```
Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>> x = pick("string", 3);
```

but then I tried:

```
Comparable<? extends Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>>> x = pick("string", 3);
```

and this doesn't compile.
It seems that the recursion is aborted after 2 steps.

Do you know of any case to make Java actually produce an infinite type?

--

Edit: it seems that the above is a compiler bug. Reading the specification, let's see how the calculation of `lub(String, Integer)` works out:

```
ST(String) = { String, Comparable<String>, Serializable, CharSequence, Object }
ST(Integer) = { Integer, Comparable<Integer>, Serializable, Number, Object }
EC = { Comparable, Serializable, Object }
MEC = { Comparable, Serializable }
Inv(Comparable) = { Comparable<String>, Comparable<Integer> }
lcta(String, Integer) = ? extends lub(String, Integer)
lci(Inv(Comparable)) = Comparable<? extends lub(String, Integer)>
lub(String, Integer) = Serializable & Comparable<? extends lub(String, Integer)>
```

So `lub(String, Integer)` should be an infinite type. Javac seems to be wrong here. Maybe it doesn't implement infinite types after all?

Comment: Keep in mind the last part of your quote: "...Java compilers must recognize such situations and represent them appropriately...".  Any compiler that conforms to specs wouldn't even blink if you handed it an "infinite type".  Add type erasure to the mix, and everything in your example just gets turned into Comparable or Object.  So unless you're building a Java compiler, you'll probably never even notice.

Comment: @cHao: Looks like Sun's javac doesn't conform to the spec. I wasn't able to produce any infinite type with it, that's why I'm asking this question. Seems like they simply left this language feature unimplemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code sends javac to an infinite loop. Presumably, it tries to build an infinite type, but does not manage to represent it as a finite cyclic data structure.

```
interface I<T> {}
interface A<T> extends I<A<A<T>>>{}
abstract class X {
    abstract <T> T foo(T x, T y);

    void bar(A<Integer> x, A<String> y){
        foo(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this example is a case of "expansive inheritance". Expansive inheritance involves an infinite loop producing an infinite series of types (each bigger than the previous). But every type involved is finite, so it's not really an answer to the question. (I suspect the question is unanswerable, because javac does not actually implement infinite types)

Answer (score 0):

This question have been answered by [R.Grigore(2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05274.pdf) in his paper *Java Generics are Turing Complete*

Take the following Java code as an example to his suggestion:

```
//an empty interface
interface Z {}

//4 generic interfaces, one argument each
interface N<X> {}
interface L<X> {}
interface Qlr<X> {}
interface Qrl<X> {}

//one complex generic, inheriting from instantiations of two other
interface E<X> extends
    Qlr<N<? super Qr<? super E<? super E<? super X>>>>>,
    Qrl<N<?super Ql<? super E<? super E<? super X>>>>>
    {}

//main class with a single function
class Main{
    //heavily nested return type
    L<? super N<? super L<? super N<? super L<? super N<? super E<? super E<? super Z>>>>>>>>
    f(Qr<? super E<? super E<? super Z>>> v) {return v;}
}
```

Comment: That paper answers a different question.
Turing completeness involves finite types of unbounded size. My question was about "infinite" (cyclic) types.

Answer (score -1):

A possibility of infinite types could be (for example, an object of Map inside a map inside a map, etc.....

```
Map<? extends Serializable, Map<? extends Serializable, Map<? extends Serializable, Map<? extends Serializable, Map<? extends Serializable, Map>>>>> objectMap;
```

(This is done to depth 5 for readability...but you can add maps inside a map infinitely deep.

I don't know if that's what you're looking for....

Comment: So how do you produce such a type? It cannot be named (would need an infinite source file), so it can occur only as result of type inference. I'm looking for an example method call where Java infers such an infinite type.

Comment: Reflection won't be able to get the type parameters -- they're gone by the time compilation is done.  "Infinite types" are only relevant during compilation, not before (type inference generates them, and handles them more-or-less transparently), and not after (type erasure gets rid of the type parameters, turning an infinite type into a normal type like Object).